# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'castorMarshaller' defined in class path resource [context.xml]:

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am tried to make Marshalling Using the Spring.**But i couldn't able to instantiate** **"castorMarshaller"** in the "spring-oxm" by the application.xml[context.xml].

While searching for the causes **i found that there is the lapse in the "spring-oxm"**.But i am using the latest version of it.Still i am getting the below error.

Can any one tell the solution to fix it.If there is the patch for this issues kindly tell me where can i get that.......

context.xml:-

```
    <bean id="XMLConverter" class="com.servion.springmarshalling.XMLConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>
<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller" />
```

**Exception i am getting:-**

```
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'castorMarshaller' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/exolab/castor/xml/XMLException
at** org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 15 more
```

Comment: Have you read the stack trace? `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/exolab/castor/xml/XMLException` is quite clear imho... You either are using an incompatible caster version or don't even have castor on your class path.

Comment: Can you kingly tell me the appropriate version of caster because i am using 1.3.3 version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add following dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- Uses Castor for XML -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
    <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Castor need this -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is Both the dependency is required?